# How to update z value when scrolled on three.js render?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add scroll event listener [to my three.js project](https://jsfiddle.net/devnigel/hL7zhuLj/1/).

I tried this code but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {

    console.log("scrolled")

    // code to increment object.position.z 

}, true);
```

I tried **OrbitControls.js** and **TrackballControls.js**, but it zooms. I don't want the zoom feature.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scroll` event will only fire if you do actual scrolling by having more content than can fit on the screen. If you have the canvas at 100% width and height the wheel won't send any `scroll` events. Try the `wheel` event instead.

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  console.log("scrolled")
  // code to increment object.position.z 
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you add your event on your canvas instead of the window element? If you can provide some code that would help also!

Comment: found the problem! scroll will trigger only if there is more content than screen can fit.